# C++ Should I fully qualified my variable type?

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++98

I am trying to write lines of code fitting under 80 columns maximum. Thus, I wonder if fully qualifying my variable type is really mandatory ? Assuming the following implementation:

```
//Baz.h
namespace loggingapi {
namespace attributes {
    class Baz {};
}} // namespaces

// Bar.h
namespace loggingapi {
    namespace attributes {
        class Baz; // forward declare Baz.
    }

    class Biz {
        int f(Baz* b);
    };
} // namespaces
```

To declare my function parameter type, there are multiple ways ?

- a) `int f(Baz* b);`
- b) OR `int f(attributes::Baz* b);`
- c) OR `int f(loggingapi::attributes::Baz* b);`
- d) OR `int f(::loggingapi::attributes::Baz* b);`

In the list above, which definition(s) is/are clearer/ambiguous for the compilers ?

**NOTE: You must assume the namespace/parameter/class/function names CANNOT be shortened in the following implementation.**

Comment: you shouldn't write the code for compilers, but for the people to read

Comment: @iammlind: i removed the redundant (d). happily not yet referenced in any answer.

Comment: Or (e) skip the ancient 80 column rule. A 24 inch monitor can easily hold 250 columns.

Comment: @BoPersson: That's an argument _for_ the 80 column rule. A three way merge can hold base, remote and local versions side by side with the output below... but only if you keep your code to <84 columns. Filling wider monitors edge to edge with source code is not an optimal use of the extra space IMHO.

Comment: @Charles - You can have two monitors if you need more space. :-) 80 columns used to be a hard limit, but it is not anymore. Obfuscating your code *just* to keep it within that limit is perhaps not the best choice.

Comment: @BoPersson: Personally, I wouldn't want a side-by-side diff split across a monitor join. Having long lines means a lot of left-right scanning for my eyes. Keeping shorter lines and shorter identifiers is less tiring, aids comprehension and reduces the potential for mistakes. It is absolutely not obfuscating code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variant **e** ?

```
namespace loggingapi {
    namespace attributes {
        class Baz; // forward declare Baz.
    }

    class Biz {
        typedef attributes::Baz Baz;
        // C++ 11 alternative
        // using Baz = attributes::Baz;

        int f(Baz* b);
    }
} // namespaces
```

Do not forget what aliasing can do for you...

Comment: Maybe aliasing is the way to go ? It would allow to fully qualified a type and create an alias and then use the alias instead. Is there any drawback using aliasing in a header for a Public API or Inheritance purposes ?

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti: Well, it means creating one more symbol that may clash in the context where you alias. In a namespace, which is an unbounded context has it may be reopened as often as necessary, it could potentially be an issue; however in a class (like here), which is closed, then there is no penalty.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the **b)** variant. My reasons are as follows:

- We assume that the developer knows in what namespace he is *now*. So when looking at the `class Biz`, the developer should know that this class is in the `loggingapi` namespace, therefore, there's no need to explicitly state it.
- The **a)** variant, on the other hand, isn't clear enough, because we should indicate that `Baz` and `Biz` are actually in different namespaces. Also, it is **not going compile**, because the compiler will look for `Baz` in the `loggingapi` namespace, and it isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose (b). It's more flexible. If you decide to move or (gasp) cut and paste `f` and it's related types to a new namespace or project then using (b) ensures that the structure of the declarations remains internally consistent.

You can choose to add, remove or rename outer wrapping namespaces without affecting the enclosed code.

Answer (score 1):

In h-file it is better to use fully qualified names, to prevent possible ambiguity in a client code. In .cpp file you can use short notation, if you prefer this, as long as there is no name clash.

Answer (score 0):

If a compiler has some ambiguity it will definitely report an error.

I believe the question should be with respect to the human reader, which is quite subjective.
The naming convention depends on

1. Pre-decided coding style
2. Where you are declaring the function `f()`

There is no clear choice over another. I would prefer that, if both entities are belonging to same `namespace` then I will omit at least that part from the name:

```
namespace loggingapi {
    namespace attributes {
        class Baz; // forward declare Baz.
    }

    class Biz {
        int f(attribute::Baz* b);
    };      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```